# Bind VNC over SSH jump host tunnel to something other than localhost port

Tags: ssh, ssh-tunnel, vnc

I know how to use a jumphost to create an VNC SSH tunnel `ssh -A -N -L 5901:targethost:5901 jumphost` however, that binds to the localhost of the initiating machine.  So if I want to bind to many hosts at the same time through something like Royal TS, it becomes a problem when you get over 10 machines.  Let's say I want to establish a VNC connection to 192.168.2.1 through the jumphost my.jumphost.com.  The command would be `ssh -A -N -L 5901:192.168.2.1:5901 my.jumphost.com`

I'd like to be able to bind this connection somehow to the target IP address so when I went to initiate the VNC session, the address would be `vnc://192.168.2.1:5901` instead of `vnc://localhost:5901`  This way I could save all the VNC connections in Royal TS.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at `-g` ssh command line option or `GatewayPorts` ssh_config option.